# Text files to test the functionality of a search engine

Tags: c#, file, search, scripting, search-engine

In the purpose of practicing for an upcoming programming contest, I'm making a *very* basic search engine in C# that takes a query from the user (e.g. `"Markov Decision Process"`) and searches through a couple of files to find the most relevant one to the query.

The application seems to be working (I used a term-document matrix algorithm).

But now I'd like to test the functionality of the search engine to see if it really is working properly. I tried to take a couple of Wikipedia articles and saving them as `.txt` files and testing it out, but I just can't see if it's working fast enough (even with some timers).

My question is, **is there a website that shows a couple of files to test a search engine on (along with the logically expected result)?**

I'm testing with common sense so far, but it would be great to be sure of my results.

Also, **how can I get a collection of `.txt` files (maybe 10 000+ files) about various subjects to see if my application runs fast enough?**

I tried copying a few Wikipedia articles, but it would take *way* too much time to do. I also thought about making a script of some sort to do it for me, but I really don't know how to do that.

So, where can I find a lot of files with separated subjects?

Otherwise, **how can I benchmark my application?**

*Note: I guess a simple big `.txt` file where each line represents a "file" about a subject would do the job too.*

Comment: Feel free to change the tags for better ones, I never know which ones fit and which ones don't...

Comment: I'm not sure many people would go to the trouble of making a text file with 10000 subjects, or bother uploading 10000 different files

Comment: @annonymously: Oh and I'm certainly not asking for that! I'm asking for a way to get those files with a script of some sort to get random articles from Wikipedia and saving them locally, maybe? I don't know how to proceed to get those files or just benchmark my application, so that's what I'm asking: how can I do?

Comment: If you just need lots of random text, with bits of information in between, you can make a script that copies the html source of lots of wikipedia pages.

Comment: @annonymously: Oh, I love the idea! Where could I get started to learn how to make such a script?

Comment: you could also loop through one page with lots of links and then copy the html of each of the linked pages as well recursively until you reach a certain number of iterations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get wikipedia pages by using a recursive function and loading the html from every page linked to by one set page.

if you have some experience with c# this should help you:
http://www.csharp-station.com/HowTo/HttpWebFetch.aspx

then loop through the text and collect all the instances of the text: `"<a href=\""`
and recursively call that method. You should also use a counter to limit the number of recursions.

Also, to prevent OutOfMemory exceptions you should stop the method when it reaches multiples of some number of iterations and write everything to a file. Then flush the old data from a string

Answer (score 2):

One source of text files would be [Project Gutenberg](http://www.gutenberg.org). They supply [CD/DVD images](http://www.gutenberg.org/wiki/Gutenberg%3aThe_CD_and_DVD_Project) if you want to download thousands of files at once. (The page doesn't state it, but I would imagine they are in txt format inside the CD/DVD iso.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the datasets from [GroupLens Research](http://www.grouplens.org/node/12)'s site.

Some samples: [movies](http://www.grouplens.org/sites/www.grouplens.org/external_files/data/ml-10m.zip), [books](http://www.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/~cziegler/BX/BX-CSV-Dump.zip)